# How to know if Task or Void method is still running when using Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await, multitasking

I am trying to use async and await and my problem is that it wont wait for the background process to finish. Maybe you are wondering why don't I just run the application synchronously?
I'm trying finish a part of my task ASAP and the rest can be awaited as shown in this example.
Thank you for the help guys! =)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
        //Problem or Maybe Not? Needs this 
        //So that my application won't close immediately
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static void Run()
    {
        Task<bool> TBool = ProcessRecords();

        if (await TBool)
        {
            //Problem #1 This Line Doesn't Show
            Console.WriteLine("End of Code");
            //SHould be safe to close the application by Now
            //But goes through here not waiting for the return
            //of the last process.

            Environment.Exit(0);

            //My temporary solution is to indicate a Task.Delay(80000)
            //to make sure that all the logging in the background
            //are all done. I dont know if there is a function that shows
            //that there are task running on the background or any 
            //other workaroung will help. =) thanks
        }

    }

    private async static Task<bool> ProcessRecords()
    {
        Task newTask = null;
        //Loop through all the records and send
        //all the records to MQ ASAP
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            //I wont wait for this Task so
            //I can send the next record
            newTask = SendToMQ(x);
        }
        //I only need to wait for the last Task to
        //indicate that I can exit the system
        //as soon as it finish
        //Problem #2 The Console.WriteLine doesnt show the last record.
        await newTask;
        return true;
    }

    private async static Task SendToMQ(int count)
    {
        //actual sending of message (Important)
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        //Process of Logging Connect to DB etc, (Not so Important, but takes most of the time)
        await LoggingRecord();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Done Processing  " + count.ToString() + " records");
    }

    //Logging of each record
    private async static Task LoggingRecord()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        //Problem #3 This Line Doesn't Show
        Console.WriteLine("Last Log Finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you setup some boolean flag or assign and check some property..? what happens when you step thru the code  is the Last Log Finished writing to the Console Main Window..?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Apparently the Logging is not finished doing his thing, but the application forces to close the whole application even if the Logging is not yet done writing, that's why i gave my application Task.Delay(8000) to wait for it to Log, but that is not just good coding making it not dynamic. thanks for all the help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use await whenever possible:

```
await Run();
```

However, in this case you cannot, so you must use Wait

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Run().Wait();

    //Problem or Maybe Not? Needs this 
    //So that my application won't close immediately
    //Console.ReadLine();
}

// note the return type is Task
private async static Task Run()
{
...
}
```

In ProcessRecords() you have the following line - I am not quite sure what you mean, so I didn't address it:

```
//Problem #2 The Console.WriteLine doesnt show the last record.
```

The above prints out

```
Done Processing  9 records
End of Code
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so caught up of using void instead it should be Task, void doesnt have the Wait(). Thanks for the new insight =).

Comment: While this is the right solution for a console application, be very careful about using `Wait()` in a GUI application or ASP.NET, it almost always leads to a deadlock.